# Updating a .csv-file that feeds my python-Twitter-bot with input

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am new to programming, so please forgive me if this is elementary.
I have developed a Twitter bot that tweets a random line from a .csv-file. Both the Python-program and the .csv-file are in PythonEverywhere. The python-program is live around the clock on the site, so I am curious as to whether any updates to my .csv-file will have any influence on the program? I would like to be able to continuously update the .csv-file and have the program be able to randomly select the new lines in the file and tweet them. I hope this makes sense :)

[Picture of my two files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WQGL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Whether editing the .csv while the program is running would have an effect depends on how it's implemented.

Your code might load the .csv once or multiple times.

Your question is too vague and with no actual code provided, it's impossible to give a concrete answer.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your reply. It makes a lot of sense that you're missing my code... My bad!
Here it is:

[My_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHQqV.png)

Now, from what I could gather from your reply, since I have the importation of my .csv-file, as part of my function, which is looped once every twelfth hour, it imports the file again and thus my updates to file should be available to the code at the next iteration afterwards.

Hope that makes sense :)